# Ubuntu login message not shown for non-root users

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, login

I really liked the welcome motd message that gets displayed when I logged in as root into my vps ubuntu 10.04 server.

It displays statistics like uptime and systemload and packages to update.

However, I secured my server and now only allow normal users to login to it via ssh.
The MOTD for these users does not display all these statistics... How can I get that for normal users too?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the pam_motd module is loaded via /etc/pam.d/ssh

```
# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]
```